# Remove all special characters in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, replace, special-characters

I'm having trouble removing all special characters from my pandas dataframe.
Can you help me out?

I have tried something like this:

```
df = df.replace(r'\W+', '', regex=True)
```

because I've found it in a recent post.
But when I execute, the special character " ' " for example doesn't disappear.

I know in PostgresSQL there is something like `[^\w]` to get a specific list. Is there something similar in python to do something like

a) keep only alphabet

b) keep only numbers

c) keep alphabet and numbers

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What do you mean "special character"? `\w` and `\W `deal with word characters, which is more than just `A-Z` (never mind non-English alphabets)  and numbers. What about eg `O'Reily`? Or Norwegian words?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[^0-9a-zA-Z ]` matches Unicode letters and digits, this will remove too much.

Use

```py
df = df.replace(r'[^\w\s]|_', '', regex=True)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/YIYfPq/2)

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^\w\s]                  any character except word characters (\p{L}, \p{N}, _) 
                           and whitespace (\p{Z})
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  _                        '_'
```

Answer (score 4):

Just do this:

```
df = df.replace(r'[^0-9a-zA-Z ]', '', regex=True).replace("'", '')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that didn't work. "M'gladbach" for example should become "Mgladbach". Is " ' " a special character?

Comment: @cvluepke strange, why?

Comment: Is there like a dictionary where I can look up which special characters are included in [\W\_]?

Comment: @cvluepke I edted my answer please check it again

Comment: @U11Forward nope still not working. The character ' doesn't disappear...

Comment: @cvluepke the real question should be what characters do *you* consider to be special? What about `O'Reily` or `fo'c'sle`? Or Norwegian words? `A-Z` can't even cover English names, eg `Charlotte Brontë`

Comment: @Panagiotis basically I just want to keep A-Z, a-z, all numbers and blank spaces in my string fields

Comment: @U11 no still not working. Just to be sure: is it a problem if not all of my columns are string-types? Should I do the replace on specific columns instead?

Comment: @cvluepke Then you should do on your specific columns

Comment: @U11 ok. And if I do it on my specific columns I need to add .str. between the column and the replace, right?
I want to understand it, so if I say r'[^0-9a-zA-Z ]' that means replace all expect everything inside the parentheses?

Comment: @U11 if I do it on a specific column it also works without the second replace()-statement. Thank you!