# Is there a way to detect special chars such as '?' or any, in a column in huge dataframe with thousands of records?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

**INPUT**

```
     A   B   C
0    1   2   3
1    4   ?   6
2    7   8   ?
...  ... ... ...
551  4   4   6
552  3   7   9
```

There might be '?' in between somewhere which is undetectable, I tried doing it with

`pd.to_numeric, error='coerce'`

but it only show first 5 and last 5 rows, and I cant check all rows/columns for special chars

**So how to actually deal with this problem and make dataset clean**

Once detected I know how to remove those and fill with their respective column mean values, so thats not an issue

Please I'm new to this stack overflow and switching from a non-IT field

Answer (score 0):

The below is an easier way without using regex.

```
special = '[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]'
df['B'].str.count(special)
```

Please refer to below link to do it using regex:

[regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65357159/remove-all-special-characters-in-pandas-dataframe)